# Zooming in Quicktime Screen Capture Doesn't Show

Tags: macos, screen, quicktime, zoom

I'm trying to record a screen capture with Quicktime, but whenever I zoom in, it doesn't translate to the video taken. I've seen videos with screen zooming in them, so I know it can be done. I repeat, I can see the zooming while recording, but it doesn't show up in the video later on.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Snapz Pro from Ambrosia is able to record the screen with zooming in and out. It costs $69 and can be found at: http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/snapzprox/.

I tested and found this works with the most recent version 2.3.3.

Edit: Fixed punctuation.